# which directory is unsafe for deployment?

Tags: permissions, nginx, webserver, django

I'm going to deploy a Django web-application, with Nginx as the webserver And I wanna deploy it on /opt/ directory. 
My question is: Which permissions should I set to /opt/ and which I shouldn't. In fact, I'm worried about security issues that changing the permissions in /opt/ will effect.

Comment: The default is the same as /usr - 0755. Is there a specific reason you want to change this?

Comment: @ajgringo619 No, I'm just asking is there any security issues with this or not? And In general, is there any security issue for any specific directory? Maybe someday I want to change it to another directory

Comment: I like using /opt whenever I need to install something non-standard, like code I build from source. For security purposes, leave the core Linux directory system alone. If your app needs special access, change its directory permissions, not the ones above it.

Comment: @ajgringo619 So you mean I should use another directory like "~/sth" ?

Comment: That's fine. You *can* use /opt; just don't change its permissions.